# How to just get key only on GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am currently using sortedCollection that stores dictionary of character (key) and number of occurrence for that character (value). When iterating through sortedCollection, how do I access the key value only?

e.g.

```
[que last notNil] whileTrue: [
    stdout << 'current character is ' *key* << ' and occurs << *val* << ' times.' << nl.
]
```

Where `que` is the sortedCollection that sorts dictionary by value.

My goal is following: let's say `que` has:
`[$a:20, $e:100]` where first letter is the key of dictionary and second number is the value of dictionary. My output should look something like this:

`current character is a and occurs 20 times.
 current character is e and occurs 100 times.`

I am not sure how to get `a`, or the key in dictionary since keys are arbitrary.

Comment: You don't show how do you build the collection que, but it seems that to retrieve keys and values, you should use a SortedDictionary or a sorted collection of Associations

Comment: I'm sorry, `que` is defined as following:
`que = sortedCollection new .`
`que := add: nodeLeaf.`

where `nodeLeaf := Dictionary new.` and iterate over `keyAndValuesDo`, which has the character and its number of occurrence

I understand that dictionary is not sorted yet, but I think I saw how to sort dictionary by value on different post, so I'll try that first.

Comment: @selfPointer Can you update the question with the actual code you have, please? For example, there is no mention of keysAndValuesDo: and how you use it in your question.

Comment: So you're saying `que` is a sorted collection of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `que` is a sorted collection and each element is an Association with the character as the key and the count as the value, as in your `[$a:20, $e:100]` example, you could do it like this:

```
que do: [:each | stdout << 'current character is ' << each key
                        << ' and occurs ' << each value << ' times.' << nl]
```

If que is a Dictionary, use `que keysAndValuesDo: [:char :count | stdout << "..." char << "..." count << "..." nl]`.

Depending on your overall application, you could also use a [Bag](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/html_node/Bag.html), which is an unordered collection of elements that can appear multiple times (as opposed to a Set, which contains each element only once).

```
characters := 'hello world' asBag.
characters asSet do: [:each |
    stdout << 'current character is ' << each
           << ' and occurs ' << (characters occurrencesOf: each) 
           << ' times.' << nl]
```

You could also have a look at the #[sortedByCount](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/html_node/Bag_002dextracting-items.html#index-sortedByCount) method and see whether it suits your case. I cannot tell from the reference how exactly its returned collection is structured, so I will not provide you with guessed example code.